$emitter.subscribe for events inside init() is not working
I have a JS plugin in Shopware 6, that subscribes to two events of another JS plugin:
One that fires after the user interacts with the page and one that fires at the end of init().
The latter does nothing. I am confused because the other event works just fine.
Both $emitter.publish have the same argument. In my plugin, they use the same method:
// main.js
import MyPlugin from "./my-plugin/my-plugin.plugin";

const PluginManager = window.PluginManager;
PluginManager.register("MyPlugin", MyPlugin);

// ./my-plugin/my-plugin.plugin.js
import Iterator from "src/helper/iterator.helper";

export default class MyPlugin extends window.PluginBaseClass {
  init() {
    const configuratorPlugins =
      window.PluginManager.getPluginInstances("TargetPlugin");
    Iterator.iterate(configuratorPlugins, (instance) => {
      // nope ...
      instance.$emitter.subscribe("init", this.onEvent.bind(this));
      // working ...
      instance.$emitter.subscribe(
        "otherEvent",
        this.onEvent.bind(this)
      );
    });
  }

  onEvent(event) {
    // do it ...
  }
}

// target-plugin.plugin.js
    init() {
        // ...
        this.$emitter.publish('init', this.createCurrentState());
    }

The init event is not inside an if statement. I tested this.createCurrentState() with a console.log() right before the event and that works.
Also, I looked into PluginManager.getPluginList(). The other plugin is in the list before my plugin gets registered – if that helps.
Don't know what I am doing wrong. That plugin is the only one which publishes an event inside init().
Code based on Michele's answer
const PluginManager = window.PluginManager;
// ...
const options = {
  dependencies: [...PluginManager.getPluginInstance("TargetPlugin")], // empty
};

console.log(typeof PluginManager.getPluginInstance("TargetPlugin")); // object
console.log(Object.keys(PluginManager.getPluginInstance("TargetPlugin")).length) // 0
console.log(PluginManager.getPluginInstance("TargetPlugin").size) // undefined
console.log(PluginManager.getPluginInstance("TargetPlugin") instanceof Map) // false – PluginManager.getPluginInstances has @returns {Map|null} as DocBlock
console.log(Array.isArray(PluginManager.getPluginInstance("TargetPlugin"))) // true
console.log(PluginManager.getPluginInstance("TargetPlugin").length) // 0

PluginManager.register("MyPlugin", MyPlugin, document, options);


Is this a JS problem or a Symfony problem?

@NicoHaase This is primarily a JS problem. Since Shopware 6 is based on Symfony, I thought the event system is also based on that framework.

Are you sure PluginManager.getPluginInstance method exists? From the class i can see only PluginManager.getPluginInstances. Maybe check that, and try to dig in the array  returned by PluginManager.getPluginList() or with the plugin returned by PluginManager.getPlugin('TargetPlugin') , the instances property is the one you have to pass as dependency

In my opinion, the problem is exactly this:

Also, I looked into PluginManager.getPluginList(). The other plugin is in the list before my plugin gets registered – if that helps.

A race condition with the initialization of the plugin. You are setting the listener for event "init" inside MyPlugin init() method which is called after TargetPlugin init(). So at the moment of
this.$emitter.publish('init', this.createCurrentState()); 
MyPlugin hasn't subscribed yet. 
Possible solutions:

Rely on the PluginManager.register() order
Declare that MyPlugin depends from TargetPlugin

Both solutions imply an edit to the register plugin logic. 
The first i think it's not much consistent, very prone to error and not clear to other devs. 
edit
--This solution is wrong
 With the latter, when you register the plugin, you can pass an options object 
// where you register all the plugins

const options = {
    dependencies: [...window.PluginManager.getPluginInstances("TargetPlugin")]
};
PluginManager.register("MyPlugin", import('src/../myplugin'), 'your-plugin-selector', options)

Then in MyPlugin class you override the constructor, which is called for each plugin always before the initialization of all the others.  This is not true, when a plugin is constructed it always calls the init() method.
import Iterator from "src/helper/iterator.helper";

export default class MyPlugin extends window.PluginBaseClass {
  constructor(el, options = {}, pluginName = false) {
    super(el, options, pluginName); // important
    // iterate over options.dependecies and subscribe
  }
}

I haven't tested the code, let me know if this idea helped.

Thank you for your answer. Your code gives me the following error in browser console: Error: The passed plugin is not a function or a class. That occurs after I switch to the import statement in PluginManager.register. Without that, dependencies is always empty in the constructor method (where you say I should loop it). Hm, is there a way to register and init my plugin first?

I think you can use a normal import statement too, like this
`import MyPlugin from 'your-import-path';
PluginManager.register("MyPlugin", MyPluing, 'your-plugin-selector', options)`

I don't get it to work. The dependencies array is always empty. I tried ...PluginManager.getPluginInstances("TargetPlugin") and with .entries(). The thing is: PluginManager.getPluginInstances("TargetPlugin") has one item. getPluginInstances should return a Map object, but instanceof Map returns false. The browser console tells me the return value is an Object with an Array prototype. .size (for Map) is undefined, .length (for Array) is 0 and Object.keys(PluginManager.getPluginInstances("TargetPlugin")).length is also 0. I am so confused right now.

could you share the code where you're registering plugins? In the question

Question edited with all console.log's I tried.

Have you registered TargetPlugin?

Of course. TargetPlugin is a third-party plugin and the other event of the same plugin I subscribed to works just fine. Additionally, PluginManager.getPluginInstance("TargetPlugin") has one item in it. I don't know why all attempts to get the one item fail. This is super strange.

@Carsten the solution i have proposed is wrong. You can't subscribe before the init method in any way if the subscriber is instantiated after the target see here.

As mentioned in other answers, init is called from the Plugin  constructor, so you cannot listen for events happening here, because your Plugin got initialised afterwards, and thus the event -already happened- when you went to subscribe to it.
There's really no good way to get to this event the way I see it - whoever did this probably didn't know how the event system works.
However, since init is only called once, you might just be able to ignore using the event, and access the state directly. This assumes TargetPlugin is storing the resulting state from createCurrentState internally on its instance somewhere (like a currentState property or similar):
// ...
Iterator.iterate(configuratorPlugins, (instance) => {
  // get the state directly from the instance
  const initialState = instance.currentState;
  // do something with the initial state, like calling your onEvent function with a fake "init" Event
  this.onEvent(new CustomEvent('init', {detail: initialState, cancelable: true}));
});

Without more context as to what the TargetPlugin does and what you want to do with the state, it is difficult to give an exact answer.
